# Añadir y eliminar clase con JavaScript

Tags: html, jquery, onclick

Estoy haciendo 4 divs que son como opciones de un menu.

La idea que necesito hacer es:

Cuando pulse en cualquiera de los `div`, se debe añadir la clase `active`.
En caso de que ya exista en alguno de los otros `div`, se debe borrar esa clase previamente.

¿Alguna idea?

El HTML.

```
<div class="row">
 <div id="depilacion" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones1 center efecto">
   <h3>DEPILACIÓN <br>LÁSER</h3> 
 </div>
 <div id="lifting" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones2 center ">
   <h3>LIFTING <br> SIN CIRUGÍA</h3>     
 </div>
 <div id="lipoescultura" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones3 center">
   <h3>LIPOESCULTURA</h3>    
 </div>
 <div id="tattoos" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones4 center ">
   <h3>ELIMINACIÓN <br> TATTOOS</h3>  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No añadas codigo que no proporcione valor a la pregunta, es decir, el codigo javascript no es necesario.

Comment: ok lo modifico!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es que segun hagas click en cualquiera de los `div` hijos de la clase `row`, le asocies la clase `active` y se la quites a la anterior.
Si quieres tener una por defecto puesta, la puedes poner en tu html o por jQuery segun carga la pagina.

```js
$('div.row > div').on('click',function(){
 $('div.row > div').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div id="depilacion" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones1 center efecto">
   <h3>DEPILACIÓN <br>LÁSER</h3> 
 </div>
 <div id="lifting" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones2 center ">
   <h3>LIFTING <br> SIN CIRUGÍA</h3>     
 </div>
 <div id="lipoescultura" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones3 center">
   <h3>LIPOESCULTURA</h3>    
 </div>
 <div id="tattoos" class="col-3 cuadros cuadros-opciones4 center ">
   <h3>ELIMINACIÓN <br> TATTOOS</h3>  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wowwww impresionante!!!!! pensaba que seria más complejo!muchas gracias!